# Ada : String legal value?

Tags: ada

In Ada, can we give a string less characters than initially specified ?
For example :

```
Text : String(1..5);
Text := "ada";
```

Is this code correct? Or are we obliged to give a 5 characters string?

Thank you.

Comment: you'll need a 5 character string in this case (fixed string). There are other options, like Ada.Strings.Bounded and Ada.Strings.Unbounded, depending on your need

Answer (score 7):

Using the type `String`, you have to - like with other array types in Ada - fill all the positions in the array.

But there are a number of tricks:

- Initialize the `String` (array) where you declare it, and you don't have to declare the range explicitly:

```ada
declare
   Text : constant String := "Ada";
begin
   ...
end;
```

- Select which slice of the `String` (array) you want to put something in:

```ada
declare
   subtype Five_Characters is String (1 .. 5);
   Text : Five_Characters := (others => ' ');
begin
   Text (2 .. 4) := "Ada";
   ...
end;
```

Use `Ada.Strings.Unbounded`:

```ada
declare
   use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
   Text : Unbounded_String;
begin
   Text := To_Unbounded_String ("Ada");
   ...
end;
```

Comment: As @egilhh also mentionned, you can also use Bounded_String depending on your needs. [The Ada Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Strings) gives a complete overview of these different types.

Answer (score 1):

The code is not correct, you must either specify 5 characters, e.g.

```
declare
    Text : String(1..5);
begin
    Text := "ada  ";
end;
```

or specify the range

```
declare
    Text : String(1..5) := (others => ' '); -- Init to spaces
begin
    Text(1..3) := "ada";                    -- Text now contains "ada  "
end;
```

or use one of the available string handling packages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible with Ada.

You can assign a string of smaller length to a fixed string of given length.
There is a procedure 'Move' defined under the 'Ada.Strings.Fixed' package.

With the help of this Move Procedure you can assign a smaller string to a given fixed string, pad the remaining indexes with spaces and Justify the copied string Left, Center or Right.

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use ADA.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Command_Line;
with Ada.Strings;
with Ada.Strings.Fixed;
with Ada.Strings.Bounded;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;

procedure fixed_string_ops is

    str_1 : String(1 .. 5);


begin


    Ada.Strings.Fixed.Move (Source => "Ada", Target => str_1, Drop => Ada.Strings.Right, Justify => Ada.Strings.Right, Pad => Ada.Strings.Space);
    Put_Line(str_1);

    Ada.Strings.Fixed.Move (Source => "Ada", Target => str_1, Drop => Ada.Strings.Right, Justify => Ada.Strings.Center, Pad => Ada.Strings.Space);
    Put_Line(str_1);

    Ada.Strings.Fixed.Move (Source => "Ada", Target => str_1, Drop => Ada.Strings.Right, Justify => Ada.Strings.Left,Pad => Ada.Strings.Space);
    Put_Line(str_1);


end fixed_string_ops;
```

compile the above code with

```
> gnatmake fixed_string_ops.adb
```

And then run

```
> fixed_string_ops.exe
  Ada
 Ada
Ada
```

You can see the padding and Justification.